# How to display @Html htmlhelper and @using in same line in MVC views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

1. I am trying to display all these three helpers in same line.
2. Popup is also not showing up asking for conformation on button click.

But the button is displayed in next line which I am creating using @using:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.EmployeeId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.EmployeeId }) |
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "BusinessLayer", new { id = item.EmployeeId }))
    {
         <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return conform('Are you sure you want to delete record with EmployeeId = @item.EmployeeId')" />
    }
</td>
```

Is there any way I can display it in same line.

Comment: it is realted to *CSS* not to *ASP.NET MVC*

Comment: I was able to write it using html like using table or horizontal list but how with css?

Comment: `confirm` not `conform` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: for displaying the button in the same line you need to set the CSS for your form tag to have the `display:inline` property. Or move the form helper to the beginning of the `<td>` (and put the ActionLinks inside it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rightly Pointed that this is question is related to CSS.Since the Entire CSS is not available i'm using inline style here.

```
<td style="width:100%;">
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.EmployeeId,@style="width:33.33%" }) 
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.EmployeeId,@style="width:33.33%"})
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "BusinessLayer", new { id = item.EmployeeId,@style="width:33.33%"}))
    {
         <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return conform('Are you sure you want to delete record with EmployeeId = @item.EmployeeId')" />
    }
</td>
```

But i strongly recommend to use CSS instead of inline style.

Answer (score 1):

The button is shown on a next line because of the `@using (Html.BeginForm)` wrapping around it. Since `<form>` is a block element, the element will be rendered on a 'new line'.

Either wrap the form around all the controls, or change the display of the form to be an inline (or inline-block) element.